# group numbers in hundred

Tags: bash, ksh

I've file as follows that has numbers in thousands. I want to group all numbers in hundreds. so, all the numbers that are less than 100 would be grouped together. As an example, abc,abc1 would be group1. abc2 and abc4 would be group2, abc5 and abc6 would be group3, abc7 would be group4 and so forth

1:

```
abc,63.5
abc1,75.5
abc2,105.2
abc4,199
abc5,205
abc6,240.0
abc7,350.6
abc8,422
abc9,410
abc10,1000
abc11,2001
```

I tried the

```
cut -d, f1 x.txt | uniq -c
```

but didn't get the desired results. Can someone please help?.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Edited for you

Comment: Thanks Gilles for editing the comments and making it more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to assigning numbers to groups depending on which hundreds belong to:

```
cut -d, -f 2 x.txt  | gawk '{ split($0/100,g,"."); print "gr"g[1]+1,"\t",$1 }'
```

result

```
gr1      63.5
gr1      75.5
gr2      105.2
gr2      199
gr3      205
gr3      240.0
gr4      350.6
gr5      422
gr5      410
gr11     1000
gr21     2001
```

If you want to sort all lines including abc...

```
gawk -v FS="," '{ split($2/100,g,"."); print "gr"g[1]+1"\t"$1","$2 }' x.txt
```

result

```
gr1     abc,63.5
gr1     abc1,75.5
gr2     abc2,105.2
gr2     abc4,199
gr3     abc5,205
gr3     abc6,240.0
gr4     abc7,350.6
gr5     abc8,422
gr5     abc9,410
gr11    abc10,1000
gr21    abc11,2001
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you simply want the file sorted numerically based on the second field.

If so, the following should work:

```
sort -t, -k2n,2 filename
```

If you want to save the results:

```
sort -t, -k2n,2 filename > newfilename
```